# build and serve fails on nz-row and nz-col

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

Getting the following error during `ng s` and `ng build`:

```
ERROR in node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/grid/col.directive.d.ts:18:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of FeedModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (ng-zorro-antd/grid) which declares NzColDirective has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

18 export declare class NzColDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/ng-zorro-antd/grid/row.directive.d.ts:17:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of FeedModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (ng-zorro-antd/grid) which declares NzRowDirective has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

17 export declare class NzRowDirective implements OnInit, OnChanges, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

At the same time Layout and Menu (from Getting Started example) working fine.

I've tried:

1. postinstall - ngcc
2. Turn Ivy off in tsconfig
3. Delete and reinstall node_modules

Has anybody had this problem, maybe i'm missing something simple(i'm quite new to Angular)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you checked with your third party library, is there any such issue logged OR try to update or downgrade the version of your third-party library and then try.... 
Or as error mentions if you have moved to angular 9  but might be library doesn't. check the version

Comment: Yes, that's the thing, ng-zorro-antd says they support Angular ^9

Comment: Then you should downgrade tp angularr8+ or if this is not a critical third party library, check any other similar library bt compatible with angular 9.

Comment: I had the same problem before. It looks like you modified the `modultes.ts` file, while it was running. Did you try to stop the app and rerun it again?